# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ende

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT S.SUPPLIER_NAME,P.PRODUCT_NAME,O.ORDER_ID,O.QUANTITY
FROM SUPPLIERS AS S
INNER JOIN PRODUCT AS P
ON S.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN ORDERS AS O
ON P.PRODUCT_ID = O.ORDER_ID;
```

WHEN i am joining three table

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not use `as` for table aliases.  Try this version:

```
SELECT S.SUPPLIER_NAME, P.PRODUCT_NAME, O.ORDER_ID, O.QUANTITY
FROM SUPPLIERS S JOIN
     PRODUCT P
     ON S.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID JOIN
     ORDERS O
     ON P.PRODUCT_ID = O.ORDER_ID;
```

The syntax error comes from the `S` after the `AS`.  The `AS` is considered the table alias, and a `join` condition or SQL clause (or horrors a comma) is expected next.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ALIASES can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.To make the heading of the output more meaningful and to improve readability of a query. [Refer link](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-alias/)

For example if you want to change the column 'SUPPLIER_NAME' As SUPPLIERNAME. This query will return the ResultSet column as 'SUPPLIERNAME'.

SUPPLIERS  S --> S is temporary name for the table 'SUPPLIERS'. Refer below modification.

```
SELECT S.SUPPLIER_NAME,P.PRODUCT_NAME,O.ORDER_ID,O.QUANTITY
FROM SUPPLIERS  S
INNER JOIN PRODUCT P
ON S.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN ORDERS O
ON P.PRODUCT_ID = O.ORDER_ID;
```